# python regular expression to check if string contains substring

Tags: python

I want to create code which will return true if the string contains the word "post". So when I give my code string like "postgre", "postgres", "sqlpost" - it will return true. How can I do it?

Comment: You don't need a regular expression for that. Use `if needle in haystack:` (for appropriate values of `needle` and `haystack`).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex for this. Just use the `in` operator:

```
>>> word = 'post'
>>> word in 'postgres'
True
>>> word in 'sqlpost'
True
>>> word in 'fish'
False
```

Answer (score 1):

If you care about matching exactly a word in a more elegant way than `if ' post ' in mystring`, you can use regex [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) which will enforce that your pattern only matches the word itself, not a substring within a word. For example,

```
>>> re.search(r"\bpost\b", "my post")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fcb95165b28>
>>> re.search(r"\bpost\b", "my postgres")
>>>
```

matches `post` but not `postgres`.